# Devise: creating extra records on user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, has-and-belongs-to-many

How do I create extra records when a user creates an account with devise?

Using a HABTM association between a User and Team model, I'm trying create a team that the user is associated with on there account creation.

Below is the code that I have attempted to use.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    current_user.teams.create(:name => 'User Name')
  end
end
```

I have also tried this

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def create

    build_resource

        if resource.save
        resource.teams.create(:name => 'User Name')
        if resource.active_for_authentication?
            set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
            sign_in(resource_name, resource)
            respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        else
            set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
            expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
            respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        end
        else
        clean_up_passwords resource
        respond_with resource
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a before_save in your model like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ... your code ...
  after_create :set_user_on_team
  # ... your code ...
  private
    def set_user_on_team
      teams.create(:name => username)
    end
end
```

See the doc here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

Comment: that doesn't look like it will also at the user to that team

Comment: It will create a team with the name is the username and the owner is the user. Is it what you want?

Comment: sorry I mean it doesn't look like it will create the association between the User and the Team

Comment: If your User have many teams and a username I think it will. Did you try it?

Comment: produces the error: You cannot call create unless the parent is saved

Comment: Ok, use after_save instead before_save. I change my answer.

Comment: played with this a bit it needs to be after_create so that it is only fired when the record is first created and not ever time it's saved

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by changing routes.rb to point to the customised controller.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users,
           :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def create
     super
     resource.teams.create(:name => 'User Name')    
   end
end
```

Comment: How did you know "resource" referred to the created object?

Comment: I knew that resource was for User because I specified it in `devise_for :users`